# Configure NHibernate to compile mappings "on the go"

Tags: performance, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

By default, NHibernate compiles the mappings when creating the SessionFactory...

Is it possible to configure NHibernate so that it compiles the needed mappings "on the go"? So that it only compiles a mapping when it needs it?

The reason I'm asking is to work around the lenghty operation on start-up (of a winforms, well, AutoCAD application...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. A good way to speed up session factory creation is [serializing/deserializing the configuration object to a file](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.aspx).

[Here are some more ideas](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/26/Real-World-NHibernate-Reducing-startup-times-for-large-amount-of.aspx) to speed this up (or at least reduce the perceived startup time)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add mappings to an existing session, you can only instantiate a new Session. A similar question was asked and answered here: [adding an nHibernate mapping at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702195/)

Comment: Ok, so let's say I "add them" when initializing the SessionFactory. So at that point NHibernate knows about the mappings. Is there any way to postpone the actual compiling of the mappings?